# How to show data from different related models in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I'm fairly new to cakePHP and I'm trying to build a simple webapp.

I have a 3 Models: Property, Operation and Category.

My relationships are:

```
Category -> hasMany -> Property
Operation -> hasMAny -> Property
```

each property has a foreign key for the category (cat_id) and for the operation (op_id).

What I want to do is show each property (in the corresponding view) with the NAME of the category and operation (the field is 'name' in the respective tables), and not the ID's. How can I do this?

UPDATE:

An example of a desired output would be:

```
ID    category    operation description ....

1     House       Sell       a house   ....
```

What I have now is

```
ID    category    operation description ....

 1     2          3           a house   ....
```

2 and 3 being the respective ID's of 'house'(category, cat_id) and 'sell'(operation, op_id)

This is the code of the Category model:

```
class Category extends AppModel{
    public $hasMany = array(
    'Property'=>array(
        'foreignKey' => 'cat_id'
    ));
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you want to do. Do you need to get the name of Category and PropertyOperation in the single query?

Comment: please write your expected output and add code of models.

Comment: can you also write a query by which you obtain indicated result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! Easier than I thought.

First, The use of 'hasMany' was not ideal. What I did was to use the relation "belongsTo" in the Property Model:

```
class Property extends AppModel{
    var $name = 'Property';
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Category' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'idCat'         
        ),
        'Operation' => array(
            'foreignKey' => 'idOp'              
        )
    );
}
```

Now the magic: Whenever I do a find() in the PropertiesController, What I've got is a two-dimensional array which contains the property data, along with the data of the tables it belongs to. :

```
Array
(
   [Property] => Array
        (
        [id] => 1
    )
[Category] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => House
    )
[Operation] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => Sell
    )
```

)
Now in the view, instead of, for instance, ['Property']['idCat'] I just use ['Category']['name'] and everything works.

Thanks for the help!

P.S.: sorry for any mis-understanding, not a native speaker.

Answer (score 0):

> properties(id, name, category_id, operation_id)
>
> categories(id, name)
>
> operations(id, name)

when you do a find on the property table with a recursive = 1 or 2 you will get all the related data automatically